# Opening a doc file or PDf file in new tab of browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to open a doc file or pdf file in a new tab on click of anchor tag. I am using MVc 4.0.
The browser tries to open a file in new tab but before that a download screen/pop up opens and restricts the file to open in new tab.I have checked on internet and stackoverflow answers where I was written to do target =_blank but it is not working for me.

I have defined my anchor link as follows. I have file name with me and that will be unique because I am creating the file name using datetime.now.tofiletime(). so, I have given my file name directly. But I first have to detect if the file is document file or PDF file or Image also.Can the below code server this purpose also?Please guide:

```
<a href="/MyController/ViewDocument?FileName=145357456705009879.docx" target="_blank" title="View Document" style="display:block;" class="ViewDetailClass"> </a>
```

Then I have below Action method in MyController class.

```
 public ActionResult ViewDocument(string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var FullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Resources"), FileName);
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(FullPath))
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            var contentType = "text/plain";
            return File(FullPath, contentType, Path.GetFileName(FullPath));
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return File(new byte[] { }, "text/plain");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the client's settings. A docx file almost always be downloaded because it can't be shown in the browser afaik. For the PDF-files, it depends. In chrome it opens standard inside the browser, but you could tell it specifically not to do that and open it in another application.

These are settings on the client-side, which you can't control from the server. Which is OK, because if that's the user's preference it will feel normal.

Comment: But Pdf also not opening. Can you please tell if my controller code is fine to open a file. If not then please guide me some example or something.

Comment: Pdf is working now. but Image and docs files are still not working.